# Add pdf to a website

Tags: database, uploads, pdf

I'm building a website containing a lot of pdf files, i added those files with `add media` button when creating a page, my question is when i open that page, does it mean in my navigator that i charged those files ( my site will be super slow ) ? or the pdf file will be charged(downloaded) just when i click on the link ?

In case my site will be slow because of those files can i put them in a database (mysql) that i have in the same server ? if not can you suggest me any better ideas ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Your website speed totally depends on your server speed. If you have a lot of visitors that are going to open/use those PDF links, then you are going to have a large number of requests, of course. This might result in a slower speed on a shared hosting.

The better way is to use a document hosting to host all of your PDFs and use the links provided by that service. This way you won't have to upload those files onto your server and you will be able to manage the documents easily as well!

You can use any of the following document hostings:
[PDF-Archive](https://www.pdf-archive.com/), [docdrive](https://www.docdroid.net/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for replaying, i will now try PDF-Archive and docdrive it seems a great idea.